# docker build running into GB size

Tags: docker

I have a Cassandra.tar.gz file which I want to convert into an image. I created a DockerFile (CassandarImageDockerFile.txt) with the following contents

```
FROM scratch
add apache-cassandra-3.11.6-bin.tar /
```

Then I ran the following command but noticed that that image size was running into GB while the .tar is only 140MB. I Ctrl+c to stopped the command

```
 C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu>docker build -f CassandraImageDockerFile.txt .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   4.34GB
```

What happened under the hood? Why did the image size go in GB? What is the right way to build the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following things to check here.

1. Size of base image,.i.e., scratch.
2. Size of build context - Check the directory from where you are building the image.

For example, `docker image build -t xyz:1 .`

Here, the build context is the content of the current folder.

So, while building the image, docker sends the build context to the daemon and which gets copied over to the image, which might be the reason of huge size.

So, check the content of the directory and see if you are adding any unnecessary files to your image.

Comment: the directory in which I was running the command has indeed many extra things. I have now created a new directory and am trying to proceed. The size issue seem to have resolved though I am still quite far away from the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The last arg to the build command is the build context. All files that you add or copy to the image must be within that context. It gets sent to the docker engine and the build runs within a sandbox (temp folder and containers) using that context. In this case, the context path is `.` aka the current directory. So look in that folder and all child directories for files that will total many GB. You can exclude files from being sent in the context to the engine using the `.dockerignore` file, with a nearly identical syntax to the `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the image you are starting from already is some Gb of size. Can you please check? See that scratch image on the `FROM` on the DockerFile